# Any way to avoid a quick flash of preceding frames when doing a seekTo() a specific time?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

When I'm doing a [seekTo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#seekTo) on a video I get a quick flash of some frames preceding the actual time I'm seeking to. Even if the video was paused prior to seek operation. It doesn't look smooth, to say at least. Is there a way to avoid such behavior? Can't it simply instantly jump to a time specified in seekTo()?

Comment: Which player API are you using ... javascript or AS3? Is it in an iFrame or an embed? What's your browser (which could have a big effect)? These could all have an effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there is the way - make more key frames per second. And if you are working with a series of small clips combined into one YouTube video, put big gaps between them (2 second long each, at least).